# Выделение ячейки таблицы HTML при наведении

Tags: html, css

Как сделать выделение одной ячейки (а не всей строки) в таблице HTML при наведении?

Comment: А разве **td:hover** не работает?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделать на `td` `hover` при наведении.

```css
td:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
        <td>текст</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```